# Running a fat-free app within an iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, fat-free-framework

I've written a query component designed to run within an iframe; it uses the fat-free framework. the app runs fine in its own window but when it is placed inside an iframe (within a wordpress site) it behaves differently. Specifically, the initial page performs the query and shows results as a table. Clicking on a row goes to a detail page. On that detail page the back button is supposed to return to earlier query results but causes the iframe to completely refresh (thereby losing the query results).

The app, stand-alone, is available at [this link](http://mvtm.ca/artifacts/query/artifact) illustrates the correct behaviour. But if I run this from an iframe (same site) the query page gets refreshed when coming back from the detail page. I don't understand why this is different.

Comment: Seems that the issue is not related to the framework but to your javascript code. To make sure, you could replace the click handler on `tr.mvt-result-row` with a 4th column named "view" containing a simple `<a href="/artifacts/artifactdetail?objectID=xxx">view</a>` and see if it helps.

Comment: That suggestion did not work; the results are the same as before.

Comment: this is not a framework issue. It has more to do with your browser history, that also could have a different behaviour on other browser if you just walk back in history. Better save the last search criteria in the user session and apply them again when the user comes back to the query page.

Comment: Thanks, there definitely appears to be different behaviors of the history object between frames and windows. I've made it so the detail opens a new tab and that works consistently across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

F3 disallow embedding pages into iframes by default.

To re-enable them remove the header `X-Frame-Options` with

```
header_remove('X-Frame-Options');
```

Note that as this command affects the header must be issued before any content is sent to output.